# regarding locking up file access in Gfortran

Tags: gfortran

In Intel FORTRAN I could simply write `share ='denyrw'` in the open statement to prevent a file from multiaccess. However in GNU FORTRAN the statement seemed not working.

What is the correct syntax to deny reading/writing of a file in FORTRAN?

Answer (score 1):

`share` is a ifort specific specifier and is not standard. If you use this, don't expect it to be honoured by other compilers. `action` may be one option, but its global for the file system. 
I don't think there is any specifier as such in fortran standard.

You will find the fortran standards [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranStandards)

So moral of the story is: either stick to standard or stick to your compiler